# How to upload multiple files from ReactJS Formik to Laravel API

Tags: reactjs, laravel, formik

I want to pass all data from Formik to Laravel API. All data can be inserted into the database except for arrays that stored uploaded files. I passed the correct name at the controller as you can see at the console log. How to solve this problem? I get an error as below at this line `$quot->quotation_file_name = $data['name'];`:

> message
> :
> "Undefined array key "name""

Laravel API:

```
$array_quotations = $req->quotation;
if ($resultPurchase) {            
   foreach ($array_quotations as $data) {
      $quot = new Quotation;
      $quot->quotation_file_name = $data['name'];
      $quot->quotation_file_type = $data['type'];
      $quot->quotation_file_size = $data['size'];
      $quot->quotation_file_last_modified = $data['lastModifiedDate'];
      $quot->save();
    }
```

ReactJS + Formik

```
<Form.Control
     className={
       touched.quotation && errors.quotation
       ? "error"
       : null
     }
     type="file"
     multiple
     name="quotation"                                  
     onChange={(event) => {                                      
        const files = event.target.files; 
        let uploadFiles = Array.from(files);
        setFieldValue("quotation", uploadFiles);                                                                            
    }}                                    
/>
```

Console log data stored by Formik:
[image: Data]